# ¿Como evitar que me aparesca un error en Datatables cuando la tabla esta vacia?

Tags: laravel, datatables

Acaban de subir mi aplicación web al servidor, el tema que como no posee datos aun, cada vez que ingreso a dicha vista me presenta el siguiente mensaje de error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podria solucionarlo?

Este es mi script.

```
function load_datatable_filter(filter_status, filter_score){
            console.log(filter_score,filter_status);
            $('#tabla').DataTable({
                destroy: true,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: "lead/list",
                    //dataSrc: "data",
                    data: {'id': filter_status,'score':filter_score},
                    type: "GET"
                },
                language: {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: 'source.name', width:20, defaultContent: '-' },
                    { data: 'request_date',width:50 },
                    <?php if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin') || Auth::user()->hasRole('supervisor')){ ?>
                    { data: 'seller', width:50 },
                    <?php } ?>
                    { data: 'contact.fullName', width:80 },
                    { data: 'contact.email', visible: false, width: 15 },
                    { data: 'contact.score', width: 40,render(data){
                        if ( data >=0 && data<=3 ) {
                            return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger text-center">'+ data +'</span>';
                        }else if( data >=4 && data<= 6 ){
                            return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning text-white text-center">'+ data +'</sapn>';
                        }else{
                            return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-success text-center">'+ data +'</span>';
                        }
                    }},
                    { data: 'solicitudes.status.name',width: 30, orderable: false, render(data){
                        return '<span class="badge border border-secondary text-secondary">'+ data +'</span>';
                    } },
                    { data: 'btn', orderable: true, searching: false,width: 10}
                ],
            });
```

El tema que me piden validar eso, y no se ocmo porque como no hay ningun datos en las tablas me presneta, por ejemplo en tablas que tienen datos pero cuando los filtro me aparece un mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que devuelve el servidor cuando no hay datos?

Comment: Ahoritica me devuelve un error 500, pero cuando tiene datos a la tabla que hago consultas no genera ningun error.

Comment: Un error con status 500 significa que hubo un error en el servidor, y no es un problema de datatables, que se ejecuta en el cliente. Revisa los logs de Laravel para ver de que se trata el error.

Comment: O ponle al script del servidor, en la primera línea, `ini_set('display_erros', 'on');` Luego ejecutas la página con el inspector de red abierto, y en la pestaña `Response` te mostrará el error.

Answer (score 0):

Haz un if si la respuesta que te devuelve la consulta esta vacia, realiza una alerta al usuario o un modal indicando que la tabla esta vacia.

Comment: En el mismo script en la parte del column???